# Unable to show content of a variable inside an email using a workflow with Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-email

I'm using Sharepoint Designer SP1 to create a workflow that sends an email.

Inside the email, I would like to insert the value of a variable of type string named: `myVariable`.

In design mode, Sharepoint Designer show this on screen:

```
[%Variable : myVariable%]
```

This was supposed to be changed at runtime to show the value of the variable myVariable inside the mail sent by the workflow.

Unfortunatly, when I open the email, I can see `[%Variable : myVariable%]` and not the value of `myVariable`.

Note that I try it using a Sharepoint Designer 32 bits and another one using 64 bits.

My workflow was a bit complex so I created another very simple one that contains only the variable `myVariable` and the action that send the email.

Another thing : before I install SP1, I had the same problem when I tried to show the content of a list column inside an email.

It seems that SP1 fixed this but not the variable problem.

Also, note that I use a french version of Sharepoint Designer 2013. I don't know if the language of the interface can be the source of this problem.

Any idea ?

Comment: There is a space between Variable and the colon. Remove this and see if everything works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already try this (remove spaces between variable and the colon) but its not working unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly, I decide to install the english version of Sharepoint Designer 2013 with SP1.

Using this version of Sharepoint Designer, when I add the same variable inside the same email in the same workflow, it works!

When I trigger the workflow and I look inside the mail sent, I can see the value of my variable.

So it really looks like a problem with the french version of Sharepoint Designer 2013 SP1.

When I compare the english with the french, I notice that when the variable is added using the french version, Sharepoint Designer put a white space between the word Variable and the colon.

```
[%Variable : myVariable%]
```

Using the english version, Sharepoint Designer does not add this space.

```
[%Variable: myVariable%]
```